# Find Specific number in file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hello I am trying to loop a file in java and output only string whose year has 2000 in it.
for some reason when I do `.trim().compare(year)` it still returns all of the string. I have no idea why

example of string in file are

```
20/04/1999-303009
13/04/2000-2799
06/10/1999-123
```

out of these 3 for example I want to get only `13/04/2000-2799`  (note the file is huge)

Here is my code I came up with so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Initiating variables
    String filedir =("c://test.txt");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String year = "2000";
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filedir))) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            //  String[] parts = scanner.next().split("-");

            if (scanner.nextLine().trim().contains(year)) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            } 
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does nextLine() do? If you call nextLine() twice, what happens?

Comment: Besides the problem that you reported: `line.contains(year)` is a really weak test; "06/10/1991-2000" will gladly pass that test.

Comment: I will read only the parts before "-"
in case someone is  wondering how will the be done i will use .split

Comment: You may consider using `line.substring(6, 10)` to extract the year (and then use an `equals` test), if you can rely on the date format being consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using scanner.nextLine() two times. That's an error. Call it's only once per iteration and assign the result to String value for usage.

Comment: Hi can you check the reply I gave to Costi Ciudatu you might be able to help

Comment: Try this code

String line = scanner.nextLine();
if (line.trim().contains(year)) {
  System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}

Comment: yes it works. I just had to change System.out.println(scanner.nextLine()) to 
System.out.println(line) so it wont do nextline again as you suggest. works like a charm thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `scanner.nextLine()` twice, which means that once you found a matching line, you are actually printing the next one.

Comment: ok I get it. I got it to desplay False  and true by removing the If statment and putting my trim in to println. but I might be using wrong logic here. whatI am trying to do is. IF year is 2000 print it on my console (actually I want to add it in a list but wanna do this my self) but cant fegure out how for the moment print only the strings with 2000 in them

Comment: You just need to check out @Alexey's advice. For each line, you must only call `readLine()` once, and store it in a (say) `String line` variable. Then you can check `if line.contains(year) println(line)`. Note that `line` here stays the same, you're not reading the next one with `readLine()`. Your code now essentialy reads: *if this line contains year, then print the next line*.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is in the while block:

```
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){              
          //This first call returns 13/04/2000-2799
          if(scanner.nextLine().trim().contains(year)){//This line finds matching value
                //But this line prints the next line                                      
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());//this call returns 06/10/1999-123
          }
    }
```

What you could do is store the value you need in a variable and if it matches the year then you print it:

```
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
          //You store the value
          String value = scanner.nextLine().trim();
          //See if it matches the year
          if(value.contains(year)){
                //Print it in case it matches
                System.out.println(value);
          }
    }
```

Hope this helps.